# How to modify DOM generated by Angular from outside, (without access to source code)?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a 3rd party Angular/Ionic app which renders a text field that I'd like to preset.

Since I'm not an Angular developer, I'm not even sure it's possible... is it?

**index.html**:

```html
<body>
    <my-app>
        Loading...
    </my-app>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="some.generated.stuff.js"></script>
</body>
```

When printed **on document-ready** with `console.log()`:

```html
<body>
    <my-app>
        <some-header>...</some-header>
        <router-outlet _ngcontent-c0=""></router-outlet>
        <some-footer>...</some-footer>
    </my-app>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="some.generated.stuff.js"></script>
</body>
```

When analyzed with the **Developer Tools** of the browser:

```html
<body>
    <my-app>
        <some-header>...</some-header>
        <router-outlet _ngcontent-c0=""></router-outlet>
        ... 
        <input type="text" id="foobar" ng-something />
        ...
        <some-footer>...</some-footer>
    </my-app>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="some.generated.stuff.js"></script>
</body>
```

When is the `<input type="text" id="foobar" ng-something />` loaded?

Any chance of being able to do something like:

```js
document.getElementById("foobar").value = "baz";
```

?

Comment: do you have access to the codebase?

Comment: or can you only hack from outside like above?

Comment: No source code, only "hack" from outside

Comment: The problem is that the inner content is changed dynamically by the angular code, you could (*I am sorry for even suggesting this*) check for the window.location to see if this is the specific route where the said input element would be rendered, and after that, perhaps "poll" with a recursive setTimeout until the getElementById returns an actual element ?

Comment: Yes, with `setInterval` I'm able to do it... I'd like a `onAngularLoadingIsOver` handler, though

Comment: Feel free to answer with that @DhananjaiPai, if no other answers will arise I'll happily accept your

Comment: I don't think it would add any community value though. Probably we can wait for someone to post a relatively more acceptable answer, and though I really doubt much can be achieved without the actual source code of the application.